# How can I repeatedly call my graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to implement graphql. I have put my graphql query within a function, FetchProducts(), because I want to call this function repeatedly. The function is shown here:

```
const Products = () => {
  let productsFilters;
  let products;

  const { category } = useParams();

  productsFilters = new ProductsFilters();
  productsFilters.setSpecificCategory(category);

  useEffect(() => {
    FetchProducts();
  }, [])



  const FetchProducts = () => {
    const queryParams = buildQueryParams(productsFilters);

    const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY, {
      variables: {
        queryParams,
      },
    });

   products = data?.getProducts;
  }

 const handleChange = (item) => {
     item.checked = !item.checked;
    FetchProducts(productsFilters);
  };

 return (...)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function 
component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this 
problem.
    at
```

Comment: Take a look at [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `useQuery` you can use `useLazyQuery`.

```
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client"

const Products = () => {
  let productsFilters;
  let products;

  const { category } = useParams();
  const [fetchProductQuery, {loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(FETCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY);

  productsFilters = new ProductsFilters();
  productsFilters.setSpecificCategory(category);

  useEffect(() => {
    FetchProducts();
  }, [])



  const FetchProducts = () => {
    const queryParams = buildQueryParams(productsFilters);

    // const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY, {
    //   variables: {
    //     queryParams,
    //   },
    // });

    fetchProductQuery({
      variables:{
        queryParams
      }
    })

   products = data?.getProducts;
  }

 const handleChange = (item) => {
     item.checked = !item.checked;
    FetchProducts(productsFilters);
  };

 return (...)
```

`useLazyQuery` index `0` return the function to trigger the API call, and the index `1` is the same as `useQuery` return values.

Comment: I am getting the following error after implementing your variation: Uncaught Invariant Violation: client.watchQuery cannot be called with fetchPolicy set to "standby"
    at new InvariantError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8876:24)
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8889:11)
    at QueryManager.watchQuery (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7734:73)
    at ApolloClient.watchQuery (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8617:30)

Comment: What library do you use? `@apollo/client` or `apollo-client` ?, I found an issue that maybe related to your problem.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9122#issuecomment-982833384